# How to mock actors in a cluster sharding test environment?

Tags: scala, akka-cluster, akka-persistence, akka-testkit, akka-typed

I have managed to setup a test environment for event sourced behaviors with akka and scala and can correctly run unit testing on self-contained actors by doing

```scala
class CQRSActorSpec
    extends ScalaTestWithActorTestKit(
      EventSourcedBehaviorTestKit.config.withFallback(CQRSActorSpec.config)
    )
```

then creating my testkit

```scala
private val myTestKit = EventSourcedBehaviorTestKit[Command, Event, State](system, MyActor)
```

and using it to issue commands

```scala
val result = myTestKit.runCommand[Response](StartJob(parameters, _))
result.reply shouldBe Done
result.event shouldBe Started(parameters)
result.state shouldBe ProcessingJob
```

Now I want to unit test an actor that in its lifecycle calls another actor, this is because I'm using the saga pattern, so the actor I'm testing is the supervisor of the saga and must call the involved parties.

So far I managed to do the following:

```scala
val mockParty = Behaviors.receiveMessage[Party.Command] { msg =>
  val reply = msg match {
    case _ => Done
  }
  msg.replyTo ! reply
  Behaviors.same
}

ClusterSharding(system).init(Entity(Party.Key) { _ => mockParty })
```

this runs ok in the first test, but then when I have to test another, say a failure case, of course the second call will not work because there's already an entity registered in the cluster sharding and I cannot override that behavior. Also, there is no way to reset the cluster sharding.

Has anyone insights on how to solve this problem? Are there other utilities for testing cluster sharding that I'm not aware of? I found the documentation a bit lacking.

Answer (score 2):

The root of the problem is using `ClusterSharding(system)` in your code which will create the real `ClusterSharding` object, which like you said you have no control of for tests. Instead, you should pass the `ClusterSharding` object from outside so that you can pass stub/mock implementation of it.

This is outline of what I am talking about rendered in Java:

Let's assume persistent actor/event sourced behavior of type `EntityA` will create and interact with another persistent actor/event sourced behavior of type `EntityB`.

Somewhere you in your application code you will have the `ClusterSharding.init(..)` call for the `EntityA`:

```java
ClusterSharding sharding = ClusterSharding.get(actorSystem); //the real stuff in the app
sharding.init(
      Entity.of(
        EntityA.ENTITY_TYPE_KEY,
        entityContext ->
          EntityA.create(
            entityContext.getEntityId(),
            sharding
          )
      )
    );
```

Note how the `sharding` object is passed to `create` method of `EntityA` and is the `ClusterSharding` object that `EntityA` interacts with.

In unit test this code will not be invoked, instead you can inject your own implementation of `ClusterSharding` when initializing the testKit:

```
//this is in test
ClusterSharding sharding = new ClusterShardingStub(); //your stub/mock
    var esbtk =
      EventSourcedBehaviorTestKit.create(
        testKit.system(),
        EntityA.create("entityId", sharding));
```

So now somewhere in the logic of your `EntityA` implementation you will presumably call `sharding.entityRefFor(...)` to get hold of instance of `EntityRef<EntityBProtocol>`. What you need to do is to program your stub/mock to return `TestEntityRef.of(..)` instance:

```
TestProbe<EntityBProtocol> testProbe = TestProbe.create(testKit.system());


EntityRef<EntityBProtocol> ref = TestEntityRef.of(EntityB.ENTITY_TYPE_KEY, "entityId", testProbe.ref());
```

And now any interactions that `EntityA` has with `EntityB` can be asserted using the `TestProbe` instance.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this approach and get back asap to upvote :) it's been a while since I put my hands on that project so it'll take me a while to get it working!